# Put json object to s3 via boto3 throws Access Denied error when adding tags

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In my serverless application I'm trying to store a json object in a s3 bucket.

```
    file_name = data['date'] + ".json"
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(data_bucket_name, file_name)
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    tags = urllib.parse.urlencode({"key1": "value1",
                                   "key2": "value2"})

    obj.put(Body=json_data, Tagging=tags)
```

The lambda function has the policy `S3CrudPolicy` for the bucket.

When I run the code locally from within Intellij it works without any errors. I can see the tags on the object in s3.

But when I run the code after it got deployed to the AWS the code throws following error.

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

When I remove the `Tagging` property from the call  `obj.put(Body=json_data)` it works without any errors locally and remotely.

I couldn't find any information which permissions the lambda function needs to be able to write tags to the object.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have s3:PutObjectTagging in your S3 IAM section used by Lambda ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy it's missing. I thought the `S3CrudPolicy` would include that. But obviously not. Thx. I will try to fix that.